# Building reliable glmnet model and constructing predictions

Tags: prediction, glmnet

I am new to glmnet.  I have over 15,000 predictors and a binary outcome for approximately 400 samples. I am having trouble finding sources online to describe explicitly if what I am planning to do is correct.

My current analysis plan includes:

1. Obtain the training parameters.
   Use the caret package to repeatedly cross validate and find alpha and lambda with maximum ROC.  I am only testing alphas between 0.5 and 1 because I want to lean towards LASSO analysis.  Code adapted from : ##http://moderntoolmaking.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html

   ```
   MyTrainControl=trainControl(
     method = "repeatedCV",
     number=10,
     repeats=5,
     returnResamp = "all",
     classProbs = TRUE,
     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
   )

   model <- train(cf.x.df, cf.y.factor,method='glmnet',
          metric = "ROC",
          tuneGrid = expand.grid(.alpha=seq(0.5,1, by=0.1),.lambda=seq(0,0.3,by=0.01)),
          trControl=MyTrainControl)
   ```
2. Use training parameters, bootstrap N times to obtain a frequency of non-zero coefficients for each variable. Assume these are the best variables to include in the model.
3. Reduce the data to only these parameters and use previous training parameters train in caret package to bootstrap for prediction accuracy.

Although I know this is somewhat controversial, is there a simple approach to obtaining the coefficients for each of the bootstraps in (3) so I can calculate confidence intervals for the coefficients at the same time?

I know I can create a single model using a "training" data set and the alpha and lambda obtained as training parameters,  and test prediction in a "testing" data set.  But it seems so arbitrary to only run the model once.

At the same time, I would like to know more about the train function in caret.  Can I specify the variables to be included in the model, or should I just create a new data set with only these variables?